# Loop through every occurrence of specific child key in a nested structure

Tags: php, recursion, tree

I have this payload,

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "T-Shirt",
    "children_rec": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Classic",
        "children_rec": [
          {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Lycra",
            "children_rec": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Plain",
        "children_rec": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Shirt",
    "children_rec": [
      {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Plain",
        "children_rec": []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to loop through every occurrence of `children_rec`.

What I have tried is,

```
foreach ($mainCategories as $category) {
    if (!empty($category['children_rec'])) {
        foreach ($category['children_rec'] as $child) {
            if (!empty($category['children_rec'])) {
                var_dump($child);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this is not the dynamic way to achieve this. What if I have 5 or 6 level of `childer_rec`. How can I achieve this?

**Edit**

@ggorlen's way is cool, but What if I need this output?

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "T-Shirt",
    "children": [
      "2",
      "3",
      "4"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Shirt",
    "children": [
      "6"
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't know the depth, you'll need a stack or recursion. Here's a solution with a stack:

```php
<?php
$tree = json_decode('[ { "id": 1, "name": "T-Shirt", "children_rec": [ { "id": 2, "name": "Classic", "children_rec": [ { "id": 3, "name": "Lycra", "children_rec": [] } ] }, { "id": 4, "name": "Plain", "children_rec": [] } ] }, { "id": 5, "name": "Shirt", "children_rec": [ { "id": 6, "name": "Plain", "children_rec": [] } ] } ]', true);

for ($stack = $tree; !empty($stack);) {
    $curr = array_pop($stack);
    $flattened[] = $curr["name"]; // or just $curr if you only want the node
    
    if (!empty($curr["children_rec"])) {
        array_push($stack, ...$curr["children_rec"]);
    }
}

print_r($flattened);
```

```
Array
(
    [0] => Shirt
    [1] => Plain
    [2] => T-Shirt
    [3] => Plain
    [4] => Classic
    [5] => Lycra
)
```

If order is important, you can `array_reverse` all arrays as you push them onto the stack without harming the linear time complexity.

---

For the updated specification, just plop the above code into a function and call it for each root node:

```php
<?php

function flatten($tree) {
    for ($stack = array_reverse($tree); !empty($stack);) {
        $curr = array_pop($stack);
        $flattened[] = $curr["id"];
        
        if (!empty($curr["children_rec"])) {
            array_push($stack, ...array_reverse($curr["children_rec"]));
        }
    }

    return $flattened;
}

$tree = json_decode('[ { "id": 1, "name": "T-Shirt", "children_rec": [ { "id": 2, "name": "Classic", "children_rec": [ { "id": 3, "name": "Lycra", "children_rec": [] } ] }, { "id": 4, "name": "Plain", "children_rec": [] } ] }, { "id": 5, "name": "Shirt", "children_rec": [ { "id": 6, "name": "Plain", "children_rec": [] } ] } ]', true);

foreach ($tree as &$root) {
    $root["children"] = flatten($root["children_rec"]);
    unset($root["children_rec"]);
}

echo json_encode($tree, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)."\n";
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "T-Shirt",
        "children": [
            2,
            3,
            4
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Shirt",
        "children": [
            6
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Is there any way I can get the index of loop?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Actually I am trying to get all products which fall into main categories. Categories parent child relation is managed in DB with `parentId` .

Comment: Put my code into a function, then loop over your outermost array and call the function on each subarray but use `$curr["name"]` as `$curr["id"]`.